# Calling SOAP web service from GWT client

Tags: java, web-services, gwt, soap, webservice-client

I don't have any experience working with `SOAP` so please help me.

i have web project with `GWT` on the client side. as for the information needed for this site, i have to call/access `SOAP` web service. i've read some forums that i should use `RequestBuilder` in order to do so. i have the following code:

```
    RequestBuilder builder = new RequestBuilder( RequestBuilder.POST, URL.encode( url ) );

    try {
      builder.sendRequest( null, new RequestCallback() {
        public void onResponseReceived( Request request, Response response) {
            if (200 == response.getStatusCode()) {
                // processing response here
            } else {
                // Handle the error
            }
        }

        public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {
            // error
        }

      });
    } catch (RequestException e) {
        // Couldn't connect to server
    }
```

This code causes an error and return `status code 0`. I think it's the [`SOP(Same-Origin-Policy)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) again.

Is there any other way I can do to access `SOAP` web service in `GWT`?

#### E D I T

In this project, a .wsdl file, which is located from an existing domain,

> http://sample.com/server/soap/soap.wsdl

is already provided. And I also have this:

> http://sample.com/server/soap/soapserver.php

How does it help me to connect to the SOAP web service?

I have created a `SOAP Client` in java but i encountered an error on javax.xml.* about inheriting the required modules.

Comment: rather build a server side mechanism for calling the soap service... and use an async call back to invoke it.

Comment: @MichaelWiles sorry, i really don't have a clue on what to do. can you please explain what am i gonna use? is `RequestBuilder` can still act on the server side?

Comment: once you're on the server side you can use any library/api you like for doing the soap request. Axis/JAXWS/simple http connection etc... RequestBuilder won't work on the server side.

Comment: @MichaelWiles in this project, a .wsdl file is provided. this file is from another domain. what am i gonna do about it? i really don't know what to do actually. sorry for bothering you... :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to access `SOAP` service from another domain then you're probably limited by `SOP`. I'd suggest building a thin server-side layer that will actually talk to the `SOAP` service. To talk to your GWT server-side you can use, for example, [DispatchAsync](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-dispatch/wiki/GettingStarted) or [RequestFactory](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory.html).

Comment: hello..thank you for answering this question. what do you mean by `thin server-side layer`? how to do this one? i really don't have a clue here. sorry :(

Comment: @rajec what dimchez is saying is that GWT is a client-side technology and you should communicate to SOAP using your server. So if you use Java on the server side use GWT to request Java to talk to SOAP.

Comment: @rajec what I meant is that you should use `.server` package in your GWT project - that is where all the actual communication to `SOAP` service should be implemented. Then to deliver data to your client-side code you could use above mentioned DispatchAsync or RequestFactory